# SSD with adapter is not displayed on startup disks list

Tags: hard-drive, install, ssd

I have a problem installing macOS Catalina on my Macbook Air (Mid-2013, model A1466).

I created a bootable USB drive with macOS Catalina. Then I restarted my Mac from it and, in Disk Utility, I formatted my SSD (connected with an adapter) with GUID scheme and MacOS Extended.

After that, I installed Catalina on it, but when my Macbook Air restarts, I see a folder with a flashing question mark. When I try to choose my SSD as startup disk I cannot see it on the list. Have you any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Are you allowing the install to complete?  When finished, it will restart automatically. If you don’t allow it to finish, even if it’s taking a little long, it won’t “bless” the boot volume and you’ll get the symptoms you’re seeing.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Have you tried Internet Recovery (https://support.apple.com/HT204904)? It could also be a problem with the adapter or the drive not being properly set to "bootable" (see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/215141/how-can-i-get-my-3rd-party-ssd-to-boot-el-capitan for details).

Comment: I wait to end of installation and after that macbook is restart and boot from pendrive again. When i go to Options + Command + R (without pendrive) i see Catalina to reinstall i do reinstall from Internet and after reinstall macbook was restarted but still see ? sign. SDD is visible into Disk Utility but not into Startup Disks. Maybe it's a problem with adapter. I wait for delivery another.